# Line tangent to the circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the equation of the lines which are tangent to the circle with equation $x^2+y^2=9$ and parallel to the line of equation $x-y+1=0$

Answer (score 1):

Lines parallel to $x-y+1$ have equation $y=x+a$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, so common point of circle and $y=x+a$ are solutions of equation:

$$x^2+y^2=x^2+(x+a)^2=9$$

If $y=x+a$ is tangent line, then has only one common point with circle, so equation should has only one solution, so you must have $\Delta=0$.So:

$$x^2+(x+a)^2=x^2+x^2+2ax+a^2=9$$

$$2x^2+2ax+a^2-9=0$$

And $\Delta=(2a)^2-4 \cdot 2(a^2-9)=-4a^2+72=0$

So $a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{72}{4}}$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hints:*

Tangent line are perpendicular to the radius at touching point.

Then this radius is also perpendicular to the line $x-y+1=0$.